# Making distinct modifications on a model

Tags: cplex, solver

How can I apply different modifications separately on a model? [The example in CPLEX documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/Cplusplus/modifyingNetworkFlowEG_overview.html) shows how to make modifications on a single solved model. However, unlike this example, I want to make two different sets of modifications separately on the original model.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot build and solve the model, make the first modifications, build and solver a fresh copy of the model and make the second modifications?

Comment: The point is to use the information coming from the original model on the modified models. By doing so, I am planning to warm start the modified models to reduce the time spent on them.

Comment: To give specific advice on the mechanics of modifying the model, we'll need to know the nature of the modifications (adding or deleting constraints, adding or deleting variables, changing constraint coefficients or right-hand sides, changing the objective function, ...).